How to Cancel a Long-Running Goroutine with Timeout in Golang?
I’m learning how to use context.WithTimeout in Golang to cancel long-running operations after a timeout. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)

go func() {
    success := make(chan struct{})
    f := func() {
        // business logic
        success <- struct{}{}
    }
    
    go f() // problematic point
    
    select {
    case <-success:
        fmt.Println("Business completed")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Task cancelled")
        return
    }
}()

The idea is to create a timeout context and handle the business logic in a separate goroutine (inside the outermost goroutine). I want to respond to the timeout signal by wrapping the business logic in function f. Once f finishes, it sends a success signal, and the outermost goroutine exits. If the timeout occurs, the outermost goroutine should also exit.
The problem:

If I call f first and then wait for the select, select will be blocked by f, meaning it won’t be able to respond to the timeout signal.
If I place select first and then call f, select will block f, so the business logic won’t execute.
If I run f in a separate goroutine, the outermost goroutine will respond to the timeout signal and exit, but the f goroutine will continue running, defeating the purpose of cancellation.
Even if I create a separate goroutine for select, it will only terminate the select block, but the goroutine running f will still keep executing.

Question:
How can I structure the code so that f is also cancelled when the timeout occurs?
I tried placing the business logic (f) in a separate goroutine so that the outermost goroutine could handle the timeout using context.WithTimeout. I expected that if the timeout occurred, both the outermost goroutine and the f goroutine would be cancelled. However, only the outermost goroutine exited on timeout, and the f goroutine continued running, which was not the desired behavior.

f() must cooperate and also accept and respect context. Otherwise you cannot stop it. In go there is no mechanism to forcefully kill the goroutine.

Further to the above - here is an example that might help.

As others already said, your goroutine has to cooperate and check for context cancellation periodically:
f := func() {
        // business logic stage 1
        if ctx.Err()!=nil {
           return
        }
        // business logic state 2
        if ctx.Err()!=nil {
            return
        }
        success <- struct{}{}
}

Then you can select for timeout and completion:
select {
    case <-success:
        fmt.Println("Business completed")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Task cancelled")
        return
}

You might also want to wait until f() actually returns before returning from the outer goroutine. To do that, you can:
done := make(chan struct{})
f:=func() {
   defer close(done)
    .... // rest of f()
}

and do:
select {
    case <-success:
        fmt.Println("Business completed")
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Task cancelled")
        <-done
        return
}


You might want to read “Go Concurrency Patterns: Context”

... handlers often start additional goroutines to access backends such as databases and RPC services. The set of goroutines working on a request typically needs access to request-specific values such as the identity of the end user, authorization tokens, and the request’s deadline.

So, for your business logic to be able to know the deadline, it needs to have access to the context.
You can read “Go Concurrency Patterns: Pipelines and cancellation“ on how to implement cancellation, but generally
        // do something ...
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
        }
        // do more ...

is a quick and efficient way to check for cancellation.
Also, be aware that starting a separate goroutine for your business logic while letting your outmost goroutine just wait is inefficient and puts unnecessary strain on the scheduler. It would be better (and easier to understand) to use a single goroutine instead:
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // business logic with cancellation added

    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Task cancelled")
        return
    default:
        fmt.Println("Business completed")
        return
    }

When you don't need concurrency or pipelines, try to keep things simple.
